# UPDATE and REPLACE for lots of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have 17 millions rows in my table, some of them contain an URL in the `[url]` column, and I want to replace some part of the URL in all my rows.

I have 8 millions rows in my table that need to be updated.

I already optimized my query a little, doing the replace by batches of 4,000, but it's still taking very long:

```
declare @Rows INT,
@BatchSize INT;

SET @BatchSize = 4000;
SET @Rows = @BatchSize; -- initialize just to enter the loop
while (@Rows = @BatchSize)
BEGIN
UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) [dbo].[table]
SET
  [url] = replace([url], 
  '?sv=2019-12-12&foo=bar',
  '?sv=2020-02-10&bar=foo')
where [url] like '%foo=bar'
END;
```

Do you have any idea how I can improve this task?

Comment: Paging helps because only 4K rows are written to the transaction log. This query is still slow though, because it searches the table over and over for matches, with each iteration getting slower as the query has to skip over more replaced rows. Extract the matching ID/Primary key values into a temporary table and use those IDs for paging.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, would you mind writing an answer so I can try it out and accept your message if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that each `update` needs to scan the entire table because of the `WHERE` clause.  One solution -- ironically -- is to skip the batches.  The `UPDATE` will take longer but it will scan the table only once.

A second alternative is an index to optimize the `WHERE` clause.  There are three approaches for this clause:

- Use a full-text index.
- Create an "expression-based" index, which in SQL Server requires adding a computed column and then indexing on the computed column.
- Create a filtered index.

The third is the simplest method.  However, alas, SQL Server does not allow `like` in a filtered index, so it doesn't work in your case.

So, try this version:

```
alter table t add url_suffix as (right(url, 7);

create index idx_table_url_suffix on table(url_suffix);
```

Then you can phrase the `where` logic as:

```
where url7 = 'foo=bar';
```

Comment: Thanks, the 'filtered index' technique kinda works. Without the index on the `url_suffix` column it took around 4 mins to update 4k lines, so 130 hours to update 8 million lines... With the index it takes half the time, but it's still taking very long.

Comment: I accepted your answer. My query took more than the week-end to run over my whole table, but it worked! Thanks

Answer (score -3):

You may want to take a look the MySQL string functions. They may allow you to do the whole thing in a SQL statement (since you're just doing a replace).

Something like:

> UPDATE `table`  SET some_text_row = replace(some_text_row, 'some
> phrase', 'some other phrase')  WHERE some_text_row LIKE '%some
> phrase%';

Comment: Why would you look at MySQL string functions for an SQL Server question? And really the actual update itself isn't the question here.

Comment: Doing this in MySQL would be as bad if not worse than SQL Server. Performing such an update will block the entire table for a *very* long time and possibly write up to 17M records in the transaction log. That's why the OP uses batching